# Modifying Docker Images Directly

Tags: dockerhub, docker-for-windows

i'm new to docker. I run docker "natively" from a Windows server 2016 with a Windows container, there is no intermediate VM (no docker machine) in between and no docker toolbox, so the "host" is the actual Windows Server that I run docker on.

Docker version:

```
PS C:> docker version
Client:
Version: 17.03.1-ee-3
API version: 1.27
Go version: go1.7.5
Git commit: 3fcee33
Built: Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
OS/Arch: windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ee-3
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3fcee33
 Built:        Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
PS C:\>
```

i pulled the image from docker hub. I need to replace the files inside the docker image while running and commit changes to the image.

Lets say i have Sample.java and datafile.properties inside the docker image which i pulled from docker hub.

i want to replace that with Hello.java and data.properties[ i pulled these files from github]

how would i do that in an automated way?  Any advise and some examples on this would he helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really don't want to do that by `commit` of image. You need to write `dockerfile` which will do what you need to do. If you use `commit` approach you will never be able to rebuild entire image down the road when base image is updated on docker hub

Comment: That's right. I can do this if I pull the image on my local machine. I'm triggering a powershell script which will create an EC2 Windows instance, install docker and pull the image it was automated end to end. I'm using New-PSSession to enter in to my newly created instance and passing the commands through Invoke-command. I'm not able to run interactive console( docker run 474614/my_repo cmd) it comes up with an error "this is not a tty device,try to prefix winpty" . I have no idea how to make this winpty to work on Windows instance.

Comment: You can run docker commands remotely by specifying -H parameter, no need for Invoke-Command

Comment: I'm trying to get a clear picture of it.

Comment: I'm trying to get a clear picture of how it works. Let's say if I'm connected to my EC2 instance by creating New-PSSession. If I run the following command will it help me to open a interactive console.                                  docker run -H -it 474614/my_repo cmd

Comment: I do have a query. If I didn't pass the commands through Invoke-command the software's are getting installed on my local machine. It supposed to get installed on the EC2 instance which I'm spinning through powershell script. Could you please help me with any samples for better understanding. That will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asking help with Invoke-Command which has nothing to do with docker implementation. Create separate question and assign to powershell queue